# How to install pgAudit extension?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgres-ext

I have postgreSQL 9.5 installed on Windows. I've cloned [pgAudit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit) repository and tried to install but there is no dll file in this repository and I could not build it.

I am new to postgreSQL extensions, so anybody know the better way to do this? or what I have to do to install this extension?

Comment: Have you thought about using Cygwin? Ref https://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

The BigSQL distribution of postgreSQL comes with tools to install community extensions like pgAudit. See https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/docs/security/pgaudit for details.

Alternatively, you can follow the steps [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules#Building_in_contrib_in_a_build_tree) to build the dll yourself. I have successfully used this method to create a working distribution with pgAudit.